# Generate list of lat/lon's within 10km of given point

Tags: python, algorithm

How to write a method that will take a central `point` as an argument and return a list of `10` points that are within 10 km radius.

```
class Point(NamedTuple):
    latitude: float
    longitude: float
```

`def _points_within_radius_km(central_point: Point) -> List[Point]`

what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: `n` random? `n` random with some distribution? A grid? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes, thanks. just 10 random points in 10 km radius within a given point.

Comment: ok then how about `return [Point(point.latitude + x/1000., point.longitude) for x in range(1,11)]`

Comment: Can you just use polar coordinates with random angle and radius?

Comment: @pault are you sure that those points will be in 10 km radius? if yes, that is a perfect answer for me :)

Comment: @petrush one degree of latitude at the equator is approximately 110 km, so each point in that list will be ~0.1 km away from the previous point.

Comment: @pault great, thanks

Comment: @pault why do you divide by `1000.` in `point.latitude + x/1000.`? 0.1km it's `100.`

Comment: @petrush you didn't specify any requirements so i proposed a trivial solution. In any case if you divided by 100, the 10th point may be outside of your desired radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formula from [this page](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), section
*Destination point given distance and bearing from start point*

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius.
Javascript:

```
  var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
  var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

To make some random points in 10-km circle, generate random bearing in range `0..2*Pi` and random distance in range 0..10. To provide uniform point distribution (if important), get distance as `10.0*Sqrt(random(0..1))`